# How to use parameters in the stored procedure to check if a specific xml element has a specific value?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to create this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
create procedure Test
    @pathToElement nvarchar(50),
    @value nvarchar(50)
as
    select top 10 * 
    from MyTable
    where SerializedXml.exist('@pathToElement[text() = @value]') = 1;
```

`SerializedXml` is an `xml` column in `MyTable`.

I get the following error:

> Top-level attribute nodes are not supported

Comment: Can you add some example data from your SerializedXml column?

Comment: Is the path to the element an arbitrary path or one level (i.e. a single node name)?

Comment: <FormResults>
  <ID>00008</ID>
  <LocationID>42</LocationID>
  <LastSaveDate>2016-09-10T21:21:36</LastSaveDate>
  <Data>
    <txtSerGen>YY</txtSerGen>
    <txtGen>0602</txtGen>
    <txtYear>2016</txtYear>
  </Data>
</FormResults>

and i want to call, for example, Test 'FormResults/Data/txtSerGen', 'YY'

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to make it a dynamic query, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t(id INT IDENTITY(1,1),SerializedXml XML);
INSERT INTO #t(SerializedXml)VALUES
    ('<FormResults> <ID>00008</ID> <LocationID>42</LocationID> <LastSaveDate>2016-09-10T21:21:36</LastSaveDate> <Data> <txtSerGen>YY</txtSerGen> <txtGen>0602</txtGen> <txtYear>2016</txtYear> </Data> </FormResults>'),
    ('<FormResults> <ID>00008</ID> <LocationID>42</LocationID> <LastSaveDate>2016-09-10T21:21:36</LastSaveDate> <Data> <txtGen>0602</txtGen> <txtYear>2016</txtYear> </Data> </FormResults>');

DECLARE @pathToElement NVARCHAR(4000)='FormResults/Data/txtSerGen';
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(4000)='YY';

DECLARE @dsql NVARCHAR(MAX) ='
select top 10 * 
from #t
where 
SerializedXml.exist('''+@pathToElement+'[(text()[1]) = "'+REPLACE(@value,'''','''''')+'"]'') = 1;';

EXEC sp_executesql @dsql;

DROP TABLE #t;
```

This will select the first row only.